# Generate a custom id college in Mysql

Tags: mysql

I want it to have the format: DNI + first letter of last name + first letter of name. I await your help, thank you

[Similar to this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/phexG.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then check the [help/on-topic] to see what questions you can ask.
Please show your attempts you have tried and the problems/error messages you get from your attempts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most efficient way is to do in your SQL INSERT statement.

For ex. if you use PHP to do the mysql insert then prepare the custom-id as per your requirement and insert it.

```
$firstname = "Sam";
$lastname = "Paul";
$dni = 1001;
$customid = $dni . $firstname[0] . $lastname[0];

INSERT INTO students (..... $customid)
```

or the inefficient way using [CONCAT_WS](https://www.w3schools.com/mysql/func_mysql_concat_ws.asp)

For ex.

```
CREATE TABLE students(
    id int AUTO_INCREMENT,
    dni varchar(255),
    firstname varchar(255),
    lastname varchar(255),
    customID varchar(255),
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

Insert the data with the customid field as null;

```
INSERT INTO students VALUE (1, 1001, "Sam", "Paul", null);
```

Update for the customid

```
UPDATE students SET customID = CONCAT_WS("", dni, LEFT(firstname,1), LEFT(lastname,1)) WHERE id = 1;
```

[DB-Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/dSM8w4Xhd7YR23xrMUGa91/0)